# Using Google Translation API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, rest, google-translate

I´m trying to make an App which uses the Google Translation API.
Since I´ve added

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
```

to depencies in my build.gradle I´ve got an Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
```

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - auto-value-1.2.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

Then I´ve also added

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
```

to depencies in build.gradle and I´ve got this Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'project.properties'

Can anyone help me here?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
}
```

Comment: can you share your dependencies{} block?

Comment: of course. here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

putting

```
packagingOptions {
            exclude 'project.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
```

into my build.gradle solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

It solve my problem in my case.

### Edit

add this before dependencies{} block

for solving

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
  // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
  // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
  // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
  exclude 'META-INF/notice'
  exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/license'
  exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

Comment: I still get Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'project.properties'